# I was working on ESP module and got some errors. Can anyone please help to resolve those errors?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

Code;

```
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

const char* ssid = "";//put your wifi network name here
const char* password = "";//put your wifi password here
const char* mqtt_server = "broker.hivemq.com";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

const byte n_rows = 4;
const byte n_cols = 4;
 
char keys[n_rows][n_cols] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
 
byte colPins[n_rows] = {D3, D2, D1, D0};
byte rowPins[n_cols] = {D7, D6, D5, D4};
 
Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, n_rows, n_cols); 
Servo myservo;
String passcode="";
String myPasscode="5432"; //predefined passcode, change as per your desire
 
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myservo.attach(15); //attach the servo on pin D8)
  myservo.write(150);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}


void setup_wifi() {
    delay(100);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
    {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
 
  Serial.print("Message arrived in topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
 
  Serial.print("Message:");
  String message;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    message+=(char)payload[i];
  }
  if(message==myPasscode){
    publish("Approved");
    dispatchMoney();
  }else{
    publish("Denied");
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("-----------------------");
 
}

void publish(String msg){

     char message[100];
     msg.toCharArray(message,100);
    client.publish("/ABC/ATM/ACK", message);
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) 
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    //if you MQTT broker has clientID,username and password
    //please change following line to    if (client.connect(clientId,userName,passWord))
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str()))
    {
      Serial.println("connected");
     //once connected to MQTT broker, subscribe command if any
      client.subscribe("/ABC/ATM/RCV");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 6 seconds before retrying
      delay(6000);
    }
  }
} //end reconnect()

 
void loop(){

  if (!client.connected()) {
      reconnect();
    }
    client.loop();

    
  char myKey = myKeypad.getKey();
 
  if (myKey != NULL){
    if(myKey =='#'){
      Serial.print("You entered: ");
      Serial.println(passcode);
      if(passcode == myPasscode){
        Serial.println("Your are welcome");
        
        dispatchMoney();
       
      }else{
        Serial.println("Password did not match");
       
      }
      passcode="";
    }else{
      
      passcode+=myKey;
      
    }
    delay(200);
  }
}


void dispatchMoney() {
  Serial.println("Dispatching money...");
  myservo.write(90); //rotates the motor counterclockwise at slow speed
  delay(5000);
  myservo.write(150); //rotates the motor counterclockwise at slow speed
  
}
```

ERROR:

```
sketch_apr28a.b:24:25: error: 'D3' was not declared in this scope
 byte colPins[n_rows] = {D3, D2, D1, D0};
                         ^
sketch_apr28a.b:24:29: error: 'D2' was not declared in this scope
 byte colPins[n_rows] = {D3, D2, D1, D0};
                             ^
sketch_apr28a.b:24:33: error: 'D1' was not declared in this scope
 byte colPins[n_rows] = {D3, D2, D1, D0};
                                 ^
sketch_apr28a.b:24:37: error: 'D0' was not declared in this scope
 byte colPins[n_rows] = {D3, D2, D1, D0};
                                     ^
sketch_apr28a.b:25:25: error: 'D7' was not declared in this scope
 byte rowPins[n_cols] = {D7, D6, D5, D4};
                         ^
sketch_apr28a.b:25:29: error: 'D6' was not declared in this scope
 byte rowPins[n_cols] = {D7, D6, D5, D4};
                             ^
sketch_apr28a.b:25:33: error: 'D5' was not declared in this scope
 byte rowPins[n_cols] = {D7, D6, D5, D4};
                                 ^
sketch_apr28a.b:25:37: error: 'D4' was not declared in this scope
 byte rowPins[n_cols] = {D7, D6, D5, D4};
                                     ^
sketch_apr28a.b:27:1: error: 'Keypad' does not name a type
 Keypad myKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, n_rows, n_cols); 
 ^
C:\Users\Malini\Documents\Arduino\sketch_apr28a.b\sketch_apr28a.b.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_apr28a.b:124:16: error: 'myKeypad' was not declared in this scope
   char myKey = myKeypad.getKey();
                ^
Multiple libraries were found for "Servo.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Malini\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4\libraries\Servo
 Not used: C:\Users\Malini\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ServoESP32
 Not used: C:\Users\Malini\Downloads\Arduino\libraries\Servo
exit status 1
'D3' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: select a Lolin (Wemos) or NodeMcu board in Tools menu